# Получить эти данные со страницы без вмешательства пользователя

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form7

Форма в модальном окне.
В ней есть n скрытых полей
В эти поля я хочу засунуть значения со страницы с материалом

```js
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("pdf-number").value = document.querySelector("body > div.calculate-mortgage > div > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > p").innerText;
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="pdf-number" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-hidden pdf-number" id="pdf-number" />
```

Получается что id pdf-number в модальном окне, тоесть он создается только после клика на кнопку которая вызывает это окно, а я пытаюсь засунуть в него значение еще до его создания.
Правильно я рассуждаю?

Вопрос, как по другому мне это сделать?

Мне получилось засунуть туда значение вот так.

```js
$( "input[name*='pdf-number']" ).val( "test" );
```

Теперь нужно чтоб вместо "test" туда вставлялась определенная информация со страницы, как реализовать?

Comment: Создайте скрытые поля в `JS` в блоке `window.onload`: 
`const hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');` и тд.

Comment: Не могу, они обязательно должны быть созданы в плагине Вордпресса, так как через плагин они накладываются на ПДФ